# Lazy loading of data from server with ListBox

Tags: windows-phone-7, events, asynchronous, listbox, lazy-loading

Quite simple Windows Phone question, but couldn't find anything about it searching the web.

I want to fire an event when a user has scrolled to the end of a `ListBox` (originally containing 100 items), so that I can asyncronously load some more items from my API.

IntelliSense didn't show any event I thought could be useful - perhaps somebody here can show me in the right direction on how I can have this type of functionality?

Kris

Answer (score 1):

Using whats given [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2011/06/30/windows-phone-mango-change-listbox-how-to-detect-compression-end-of-scroll-states.aspx) you can detect the end of scrolling and trigger an event on the code behind which will call for more items. Once you add them to your `Observable Collection` which will be bounded to your listbox's itemsource. The items will appear automatically. I hope it helps :)